# Encrypting Communication with SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I have a SQL Server database with some sensitive info. I want to encrypt communications between this database and a remote webservice. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encrypt the connection using SSL:

- [Encrypting Connections to SQL Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

1. There's [encryption](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/) available in Sql Server (symmetric, asymmetric keys, certificates).
2. An [endpoint with SSL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181591.aspx) and encryption.